# saving buyer's card info after paypal express checkout

Tags: database, paypal, security, online-store

I want to implement an express paypal checkout for my website.
People basically choose an item and buy it. There is no recurring
payments or so. Do I have to save buyer's card info in addition
to transaction and order id ? If yes what should I store in my
database ? I basically don't want to deal with credit cards security
and stuff on my side in case my db got hijacked.

Comment: Anybody who thinks their database is secure is being ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

By using express checkout the customer won't be entering any card details into your site.  That is all handled at PayPal.

PayPal has great documentation with flows.
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted